# Using net/imap connecting to imap.google gives error

Tags: ruby, imap

I am trying connect to my mail server using `net/imap` i get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>               12: from imap.rb:15:in `<main>'
>               11: from imap.rb:5:in`method_name'
>               10: from imap.rb:5:in `new'
>                9: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/imap.rb:1089:in`initialize'
>                8: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/imap.rb:1132:in `tcp_socket'
>                7: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:631:in`tcp'
>                6: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
>                5: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:227:in`each'
>                4: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:641:in `block in tcp'
>                3: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:137:in`connect'
>                2: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:56:in `connect_internal'
>                1: from /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:1213:in`connect_nonblock'
>       /home/radoslav/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:1213:in `__connect_nonblock': Network is unreachable - connect(2) for [2a00:1450:400c:c07::6d]:143 (Errno::ENETUNREACH)

and this is the code I am using:

```
require 'net/imap'

def method_name
    imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com')
    imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'my.name.here@gmail.com', 'mypasshere')
    imap.examine('INBOX')
    imap.search(["RECENT"]).each do |message_id|
        puts "#{message_id}"
    end
    puts "Hello"
end


method_name()
```

I suspect this has something to do with the system rather than the gem itself but couldn't find the solution in internet.

The machine has internet access for sure.

```
radoslav@radoslav-VirtualBox:~/Documents/Ruby/imap$ telnet imap.gmail.com 993
Trying 74.125.140.109...
Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on error backtrace its trying to connect via tcp port 143:

```
Network is unreachable - connect(2) for [2a00:1450:400c:c07::6d]:143
```

and you tested it via 993:

```
radoslav@radoslav-VirtualBox:~/Documents/Ruby/imap$ telnet imap.gmail.com 993
```

143 is a default value for imap based on [`docs`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-c-new) so change this line to pass correct port number:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', port: 993)
```

Comment: Also make sure you're configured for SSL.

Comment: It also looks like it's trying to connect via IPv6, which may not be configured properly?